# Add constraints to typealiases inside Swift protocols

Tags: swift, swift2

How can I indicate that `B.Generator.Element` should be `A`?

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias A
    typealias B: CollectionType
    func f(a: A) -> B
}
```

I realise that I can do `func f(node: B.Generator.Element) -> B` and eliminate `A` altogether, but I can't do this if `A` is defined in some other protocol and `SomeProtocol` inherits from it.

**Edit:**

Added example

```
protocol P {
    typealias A
}

protocol Q: P {
    typealias B: CollectionType
    typealias A = B.Generator.Element
    func f(node: A) -> B
}

func g<A, T: Q where A == T.A>(arg1: T, arg2: A) {
    let collection = arg1.f(arg2)
    collection.contains(arg2) // Error here
}
```

**Edit 2:**
To clarify, I am looking to somehow specify `A == B.Generator.Element` in the protocol itself since I must use a free function. I found a [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/46217#46217) in the developer forums with precisely my problem. Looks like its a limitation in the current type system. I've filed a radar, let's hope it gets resolved :)

**Edit 3:**
A radar already exists for the issue. Use rdar://21420236 while filing.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    typealias A = B.Generator.Element
    typealias B: CollectionType
    func f(a: A) -> B
}
```

**Edit:**

The error you're getting is because there's no guarantee `A` (`B.Generator.Element`) conforms to `Equatable`. Therefore you can't call `contains` on `collection` since `contains` is defined as:

```
extension SequenceType where Generator.Element : Equatable {
    public func contains(element: Self.Generator.Element) -> Bool
}
```

(I'm not sure why Xcode is presenting `contains` as a valid method to call, could be a bug...)

To solve this you can do:

```
// Since you're using Swift 2 you could use a protocol extension instead of a free function.

// Unfortunately, Xcode complains without the explicit declaration that `A` is 
// `B.Generator.Element`.
extension Q where A: Equatable, A == B.Generator.Element {
    func g(elem: A) {
        let collection = f(elem)
        collection.contains(elem)
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is that `A` is not guaranteed to be `B.Generator.Element` always. So, I cannot use functions like `append` on an instance of `B` with an instance of `A`. An Xcode rightly flags this as an error...

Comment: Do you think you could post that example? Perhaps you could add some more detail about exactly what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: This may actually be a bug, the need for `A = B.Generator.Element`

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking to somehow specify `A == B.Generator.Element` in the protocol itself since I must use a free function. `contains` is entirely my fault - I stripped it down too much. I found a [thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/46217#46217) in the developer forums with precisely my problem. Looks like its a limitation in the current type system. I've file a radar, let's hope it gets resolved :)